# how to add multiple different firebase api keys of android for sending push using parse server?

Tags: android, firebase, parse-platform, push-notification

My server has different applications connected to the server and i would like to add all the api keys & sender id in my index.js from google developer (firebase for push) ,soo i can send push to all.
In ios we can add like an array,how to add different android apps with different apikeys?

```
push:{android: {senderId: "FCM senderId",apiKey: "FCM server API key"},
ios:[{pfx: 'first app.p12',passphrase: '',topic: '1bundle id',production: true},
{pfx: 'next app.p12',passphrase: '',topic: '2 bundle id',production: true}]}
```

Comment: I believe that's not currently possible and you would have to create a custom Push Adapter.